# How can I use the power coming from the GFI plug to power a three-way switch in the kitchen

Tags: electrical, wiring

How can I use the power coming from the GFI plug to power a three-way switch in the kitchen for a light. I have 14-3 wire going from one switch to the other switch and I have 12-2 coming from the GFI plug to three outlets on the GFI can I power a three-way switch from the last outlet for power to the light in the kitchen? The GFI keeps blowing

Comment: You need to wire it correctly or the GFCI will trip.  Are you doing anything with the "LOAD" terminals that you should not be doing"?

Comment: What area/space does that GFCI serve?

Comment: Oh Crap.  If you've got 12/2 in a kitchen area, it's certainly on a 20 amp breaker.  You can't connect 14 ga, it's only rated for 15 amps.  Not only that, those circuits (minimum of 2) are required to be dedicated to small kitchen appliances.    Is there another place you can get power from that isn't part of the kitchen circuits? It's always best practice to separate outlets from lighting anyway.